What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
As per "The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta":

Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger.
  You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What
  would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes
  what your site is about. Every word counts!
Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

Examples of "pitches", taglines and mottos

The tagline:
< placeholder >  
The motto:
< placeholder >
The blurb under the logo:
< placeholder >
A convenience redirect “nickname” for the site:
< placeholder >
Perhaps eventually the domain name in some form:
< placeholder >


I don't know if the discussion about the site subdomain, applies as the redirect "nickname"?

Perhaps this Are 51 discussion can be useful for inspiration.

Tag Line
Reverse Engineering: One step backwards, two steps forward.
Domain name:
re.stackexchange.com
reversing.stackexchange.com

I was thinking that some reversed version of the phrase "Trust me, I'm an engineer" could serve as our site motto.

"Trust me, I'm an reenigne"

Maybe the opposit, like stack underflow

"MOV EDI, EDI" so we could later patch a better tagline

@zv_: in this case I would suggest a longer nop than a 2-byte one ;)


tagline: techniques to understand how things actually work.
nickname: StackReverse


I just thought "stuck in reverse" when I saw your "StackReverse" :)

Tagline

Reversing is not about breaking things, but understanding it.

Tagline 2

Reverse-engineering: The ultimate hacker's science.

Domain name
reverseengineering.stackexchange.com



"stuck in reverse" as mentioned by @0xC0000022L felt right the moment I read it.
"the best way to understanding is to reverse engineer it" - or some variation of this sentence using proper grammar



I find Ange's idea best w.r.t. the nickname: StackReverse
I find part of QAZ' answer best w.r.t. the domain name: re.stackexchange.com, along with the existing reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

As for possible tag lines here are my ideas:

Advancing knowledge in reverse
Stuck in reverse
What the hex?

Number 2 was mentioned in a comment on another answer.

I dont think we will get re because of the reasons mentioned by Robert Cartaino. If it is an option, then yes, this would be best.

The tagline: Reverse Engineer, Think Forward
Domainname: rce.stackexchange.com

In simple terms, the elevator pitch :

We break things down. One step at a time.

Domain name :

reve.stackexchange.com

Pronounced as Rev E. 

@CamilStaps How about reveng.stackexchange pronounced revenge ? That will certainly draw a lot of traffic and attention ;-)
